# Django how to update a template without refreshing/redirecting?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to make a simple commenting system where someone can add their comment to a post and it'll show up without having to redirect them or refresh the page. This is what my code basically looks like:

```
def post_details(request):
    details = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
      request.POST
      # Function here for creating a new comment
      details['new_comment'] = new_comment
      details['post_details'] = post_details
    else:
      details['post_details'] = post
    return render(request, 'post_details.html', details)
```

The `post_details.html` shows a post with comments below it along with a form that adds their comment. I tried to add a new block of code in the template file for `new_comment` and the issue is that when I add a new comment, it will update that part but adding another one won't show up.

I should also note that I have CSV files that store the post and comment details. In my `models.py` file, I have my classes and methods to read in the CSV files so the function I left out does update the file with the comments. I'm trying to do this without Javascript but I'm open to trying anything, just really want to solidify my understanding of requests. I hope this wasn't confusing.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use JavaScript (AJAX) in this situation.**

- Create a base division in your template for showing your comments.
- Then create an input form field for user to write comment.
- Give the submit button id such as "addcomment" in my case.
- Create the below ajax function with proper input values.

**AJAX Function in JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#addcomment').click(function(){
            // Taking_username_from_input_field_with_id_username.
            var user = $('#username').val(); 
            var usercomment = $('#usercomment').val(); // Taking_comment_from input_field_with_id_usercomment.
            var csr = "{{csrf_token}}"; // Creating CSRF Token
            $.ajax({
              url: "{% url 'savecomment' blog.blog_id %}",
              method:"POST",
              data:{
                user:user,
                usercomment:usercomment,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:csr
              },
              success:function(data){
                form.reset(); // resetting form values. 
                var output = "";
                output =` <div class="comment">
                        <div class="comment-header d-flex justify-content-between">
                          <div class="user d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="image"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></div>
                            <div class="title"><strong>${data.user}</strong><span class="date">${data.date}</span></div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="comment-body">
                          <p>${data.comment}</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>`
                  
              $('.post-comments').append(output); // Appending data_in existing values which loaded_in first run.
              //for_updating commentcount
              var commentcount = data.number_of_comments;
              $('.no-of-comments').replaceWith(`<span class="no-of-comments">(${commentcount})</span>`);
              }
            });
```

**COMMENTS TEMPLATE**

```
<div class="post-comments">
                  <header>
                    <h3 class="h6">Post Comments<span class="no-of-comments">0</span></h3>
                  </header>
</div>
```

**FORM TEMPLATE**

```
<form id="form" action="#" class="commenting-form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="username" value="{{page.username}}" id="username" placeholder="Name"
                class="form-control" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <textarea name="usercomment" id="usercomment" placeholder="Type your comment"
                class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <button id="addcomment" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit Comment</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```